# Reporting data from view in rails after_filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to log the number of cache misses for certain blocks in my views.  I do the log storing in an after_filter in my controller.

It doesn't seem possible to manipulate instance variables inside of views. What's the best way to store information during view rendering that is then made available to a controller's after_filter?

Comment: I hope finally cache misses would get recorded somewhere through model, why not let a model handle this, let a model be a middle person, holding data in between, which both controller and view can access any time.

Comment: Is it easy to hold this data in a model in a thread-safe way? The cache-miss statistics seem like they should be removed from model logic as they're only related to the view rendering itself (this is cached HTML).

Comment: Do you already smelling any threading issue? As in all of your comments you seem to have concerns about thread-safe.

Comment: I've had threading problems storing controller data in models before, solved using the `Thread.current[]` construct.

Comment: (which I should point out is generally a bad thing to do, but sometimes your problem just doesn't fit the MVC separation and it's not worth forcing that model)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best solution, but it works in a test rails app:

Add a method to your controller. It must be public, unless you're ok using `send` to call it.

```
def increment_miss
  @miss_count ||= 0
  @miss_count += 1
end
```

Then an after_filter (I've restricted mine to `:index`):

```
after_filter :only => :index do
  Rails.logger.info("miss_count: #{@miss_count.to_i}")
end
```

Then call the method in your view as many times as you need to:

```
<% controller.increment_miss %>
```

You may want to modify the method to take an optional `increment_by` param if you want to be able to increment by more than 1 per call.

Comment: do you know how this interacts with threading? Will `@miss_count` be shared across all threads running on that instance of the app, or is it local to the request?

Comment: `@miss_count` is local to the thread serving the current request, just like any other controller instance variable (e.g. those used to store objects to be passed to the view). Rails creates a new controller instance for every request.

Comment: that makes sense to me. I'll come back and accept this after I get a chance to implement it in the next couple of days. Thanks for the help.

Comment: views manipulations stays in views only, sorry Kelvin, this does not work.

Comment: @AmolPujari That is only true for certain changes the views make, such as setting an instance variable. But if the view calls a method that mutates the controller's state, that change persists and is available to the `after_filter`. Have you actually tried the code?

Comment: yes, I tried out with rails 3.2.3, it wasn't that way as you saying.

Comment: This solution is working for me.  I did use `helper_method :increment_miss` instead of making it a public method.

Comment: @spike yes, helper method is a bit cleaner if you don't want to explicitly reference the controller in the view code.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider moving the logic into a dedicated model  object.

```
class MyController > ApplicationController
  around_filter :record_cache_misses

  def record_cache_misses
    @cache_miss_logger = CacheMissLogger.new
    yield
    @cache_miss_logger.persist_count
  end
end
```

And in the view it would be a normal method call.

```
<% @cache_miss_logger.increment_count %>
```

Comment: It seems overkill to create a separate class just to hold the value. Why do this instead of the instance-variable idea of @kelvin ?

Comment: Hi Spike.  The other answer would work fine, too.  It's a matter of preference.  I think I'm still highly influenced by Avdi Grimm's Objects on Rails books with its emphasis on small, single responsibility classes.

Comment: Depending on what `persist_count` does, there could be a race condition. Just writing to a log shouldn't be a problem though.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest,

1. There is no straight forward way to achieve this as its not per rails MVC rule, and in any way it is not doable(unless you change rails)
2. You deal with data that has scope starting from and ending with views, so why to go reverse and make controller responsible for logging/utilizing it, let view/helper method log it
3. So you may initiate it in controller, you may have referred to cache in controller, take it forward, let view manipulate it, and in views/helpers you can log it, keep a separate log storing module/file take care of this concern, let helper include it, call it from views.

Comment: Sure, you could make it a helper method, but then you'd have to make sure to call it in the view *after* you've finished counting *all* the cache misses. This makes it very fragile because you have to remember to move the method call further down every time you add new code to that view file that needs to increment the counter. It gets even more confusing with partials.

Comment: you should have a space after footer in the layouts

Answer (score 0):

I found one more way out, I hope/guess it would be thread-safe, would be great if anybody confirms

```
# in controller
before_filter :foo
after_filter :bar

def foo
  class << @cache_miss
    attr_accessor :count
  end

  @cache_miss.count = 1
  puts "----------#{@cache_miss.count}" # => 1
end

def bar
  puts "----------#{@cache_miss.count}" # => 2
end

#in views
<% @cache_miss.count = 2 %>
```

Comment: Where are you assigning `@cache_miss`? If you don't assign it, you'll be adding the singleton accessor to the global `nil` object. Also, it will only be thread safe if you set it to an object that isn't shared. You could use an `OpenStruct`.